# How to calculate the average from a list of records

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, datetime

So i am working on an Assignment and seem to be having trouble when it comes to calculating an average from a list of data (the data is read from an external .txt file). Specifically what i am trying to do is to read data records from the list of data below.

```
1-2-2014,Frankton,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,Glenview,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,Glenview,63277.9,32
10-5-2015,Glenview,83290.09,16
11-6-2015,Frankton,81301.82,34
10-10-2015,Frankton,62333.3,40
11-11-2015,Frankton,28998.8,29
1-1-2016,Glenview,51083.5,27
1-3-2016,Glenview,62155.72,42
27-3-2016,Frankton,33075.1,18
2-4-2016,Glenview,61824.7,35
```

After the above data has been read and stored as records e.g.

1-2-2014 as [rec0]Frankton[rec1]42305.67[rec2]67,23[rec3].

I am needing to prompt the user to enter a store name (either Frankton or Glenview) from the list of records, then calculate the total rec2 from all the records combined that are from the user's entered store. I am also needing to do the same for the average, e.g. calculate the average of rec[3] from the user's entered store.

Currently the total and total transaction is printing correct but the average and average transaction is not displaying with the correct numbers.

The correct output i am looking for when i run this program will be -

The user enters **Frankton**

[image]
or the user enters **Glenview**

[image]

My current code will be posted below:

```
from datetime import datetime

def readdata(filename):
    print('*' * 10, 'Reading Records From ', filename, '*' * 10)
    print('Done.\n\n')
    data = []
    readf = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in readf :
        datestr, branch, dailySale, transactions = line.split(',')
        dateobj = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d-%m-%Y')
        rec = [dateobj, branch, eval(dailySale), int(transactions)]
        data.append(rec)
readf.close()

return data

def query_branch_sale(records):
    print('*' * 10, 'Querying Total Sales by Branch', '*' * 10)
    branch = input('Enter branch name (Glenview or Frankton): ')
    while branch != 'Glenview' and branch != 'Frankton' :
        print('Invalid. Enter again.')
        branch = input('Enter branch name (Glenview or Frankton): ')
    total = 0
    total_transaction = 0
    for rec in records: 
        if rec[1] == branch:
            total = total + rec[2]
            total_transaction = total_transaction + rec[3]
    average = total/len(records)
    ave_transaction = total_transaction/len(records)
    print(total)
    print(average)
    print(total_transaction)
    print(ave_transaction)

def main():

    records = readdata('data.txt')
    query_branch_sale(records)

main ()
```

Comment: `readf.close()` and `return data` need to be indented so they're part of the `readdata()` function.

Comment: Why are you using `eval(dailySale)`? It should be `float(dailySale)`.

Comment: You should also use `with open(filename, 'r'):`, the `with` keyword will automatically close the file, even if an exception occurs before the block is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't divide by `len(records)` when calculating the averages, because `records` includes the transactions from other branches. You need to add a counter variable that counts the number of transactions from the selected branch, and divide by that.

```
total = 0
total_transaction = 0
count = 0
for rec in records: 
    if rec[1] == branch:
        total = total + rec[2]
        total_transaction = total_transaction + rec[3]
        count += 1
if count > 0:
    average = total/count
    ave_transaction = total_transaction/count
else:
    average = 0
    ave_transaction = 0
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much, your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas`!

```
from pandas import read_csv

def get_sum_and_mean(city):
    with open('records.csv', 'r') as open_file:
        records = read_csv(open_file, header=None)

    records = records.groupby(1)
    return records[2].sum()[city], records[3].mean()[city]
```

Basically, `records.groupby(1)` groups the data frame by city, `records[2].sum()[city]` calculates the sum of the 3rd for each city and extracts the city that you want, and `records[3].mean()[city]` does the same for the average of the 4th column.

Comment: Homework assignments disallow pandas

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas is much easier for playing around with tables, but if you're not familiar with pandas, spliting columns and lines apart with `line.split(',')` is helpful, then using it with `line[column_number]` to get total or average results. besides I prefer seperating two branches at first and caculating the total and average numbers later.

```
def get_your_money():

    with open(<your-text-file>, 'rb') as f:
        lst = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    table = [line.split(',') for line in lst]


    while True:
        rec1 = raw_input('Enter branch name (Glenview or Frankton): ')
        if not rec1 in ['Glenview', 'Frankton']:
            print 'Invalid, Enter again.'
            continue
        else:
            rec2 = [float(line[2]) for line in table if line[1] == rec1]
            rec3 = [int(line[3]) for line in table if line[1] == rec1]

            if len(rec2) != 0 and len(rec3) != 0:
                print 'Total sale by {} ${:,.2f}'.format(rec1, sum(rec2))
                print 'Average sale by {} ${:,.2f}'.format(rec1, sum(rec2) / len(rec2))
                print 'Total transactions by {} ${:,}'.format(rec1, sum(rec3))
                print 'Average transactions per day by {} ${:,}'.format(rec1, sum(rec3) / len(rec3))
            else:
                rec2_avg = rec3_avg = 0

            break
```